# Add client proxy with Apache CXF 3 and JAX-RS 2.0

Tags: java, rest, proxy, jax-rs, cxf

I try to add a proxy to my **Apache CXF 3** client API.

```
ClientBuilder.newClient().target(serverUri)
                         .request()
                         .post();
```

With Jersey implementation I use ClientConfig :

```
ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
config.connectorProvider(new ApacheConnectorProvider());
config.property(ClientProperties.PROXY_URI, proxyAddress);
ClientBuilder.newClient(config) ...
```

And i would like to do the same thing with CXF 3 without using their specific client (I use JAX-RS client implementation) and not setting the proxy on the JVM.

Any help will be apriciated ;)

**EDIT :**

A start of solution can be :

```
client.property("http.proxy.server.uri", proxyUri); 
client.property("http.proxy.server.port",proxyPort);
```

But i didn't found properties for proxy authentification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't use JAX-RS client, it is just an interface, see [JAX-RS API](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html). The implementation is Apache CXF client, see [JAX-RS 2.0 Client API](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-client-api.html#JAX-RSClientAPI-JAX-RS2.0ClientAPI):

> CXF 3.0.0 implements JAX-RS 2.0 Client API. Internally it is implemented in terms of CXF specific WebClient.

You can use Apache CXF client configuration, see [Apache CXF API](https://cxf.apache.org/javadoc/latest/org/apache/cxf/jaxrs/client/ClientConfiguration.html):

> Represents the configuration of the current proxy or WebClient. Given an instance with the name 'client', one can access its configuration using a WebClient.getConfig(client) call.

Example:

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
HTTPConduit conduit = WebClient.getConfig(client).getHttpConduit();

HTTPClientPolicy policy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
policy.setProxyServer("my.proxy.domain");
policy.setProxyServerPort(80);
conduit.setClient(policy);

ProxyAuthorizationPolicy policy = new ProxyAuthorizationPolicy();
policy.setAuthorizationType("Basic");
policy.setUserName(PROXY_USER);
policy.setPassword(PROXY_PWD);
conduit.setProxyAuthorization(policy);
```